# To add values from one table to another table and their dependent values from another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In the below code this is a exam course table with 2 columns are in drop down exam name and course code. My aim is when i select course code it should get dependent value subject code from course subject table and relevant subject name for subject code from subject master table and added to course details table.

I have tried when i add exam name and course code it is added in exam course and course  details table(ie.course code)course code is added to course details table.Pls anyone help me.

Tables

### Exam course

exam name| course code

Course subject

course code |subject code

subject master

subject code | subject name

course details

course code | subject code | subjectname

```
   Controller examcourse_site

function index()
    {   
        if($query = $this->examcourse_model->get_records())
        {
            $data['exam_records'] = $query;
        }
        //to display data form another table and append in this table examcourse
        if($query = $this->examcourse_model->get_exam_table_records())
        {
            $data['examname_records'] = $query;
        }
            //to display data form another table and append in this table examcourse        
        if($query = $this->examcourse_model->get_course_code_records())
        {
            $data['course_records'] = $query;
        }
        $this->load->view('examcourse_view', $data);
    }
    function create()
    {
        $j=1;
        $createcustomer = $this->input->post('createcustomer');
        if( $this->input->post('createcustomer') != false ){
        foreach ($createcustomer as $j)
        {
        $data = array(
            'exam_name' => $this->input->post('exam_name_id'.$j),
            'course_code' => $this->input->post('course_code_id'.$j)
        );

        //$course_code= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["course_code_id".$j]);
        $exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name_id'.$j);
        if ($exam_name != ""){
            $this->examcourse_model->add_record($data, $exam_name);
        }
        $j++;   
        }
    }
    $this->index();
    }
```

model:

```
    function get_records()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('examcourse');
        return $query->result();    
    }
    function add_record($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('examcourse', $data);
        $this->db->insert('course_table', $data);
        return ;
    }
    function get_exam_table_records()
    {
        $this->db->select("CONCAT(exam_name, ' ', month,' ',year) AS fullexamname", FALSE);//this will concat the value
        $query = $this->db->get('exam_table');
        return $query->result();
    }
    //to get the record from coursemaster table
    function get_course_code_records()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('coursemaster');
        return $query->result();    
    }
```

Comment: seems you need ajax here

Comment: Can u give me some reference of using ajax @Drixson Oseña